# Make all Django models inherit from certain class

Tags: python, django

I wrote a certain function that I'd like all my Django models to have. What's the best way to make all my models inherit from a certain class?

What I tried didn't work. I made a new class like this:

```
from django.db import models

class McifModel(models.Model):
    pass
```

And then I did this in another model:

```
from django.db import models, connection, transaction
from mcif.models.mcif_model import McifModel

class Customer(mcif.models.McifModel):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    customer_number = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    social_security_number = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=33)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    deceased = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    do_not_mail = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./import.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mcif.models import GenericImport, Customer, CSVRow
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mcif.models.account_address import AccountAddress
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/account_address.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mcif.models.account import Account
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/account.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mcif.models.customer import Customer
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/customer.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Customer(mcif.models.McifModel):
NameError: name 'mcif' is not defined
```

Comment: You should be careful when dealing with inheritance in Django. Unless the parent class is declared as abstract, every time you query for a child class that is inheriting from it the database will be doing a JOIN which may impact performance. If you only need them all to share a function you would be better off declaring the parent model as abstract which would give you the same functionality but better performance.

Comment: How do I do that? I don't see any clear examples when I google "python abstract class". (I'm familiar with abstract classes in other languages but in Python it doesn't seem straightforward.)

Comment: More specifically: it doesn't seem like you can make classes abstract in Python, only methods. Since I don't have any methods in McifModel, I don't understand what to do.

Comment: It's Django, not python specific: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't import `mcif` -- you imported `McifModel`. Try this:

```
from mcif.models.mcif_model import McifModel

class Customer(McifModel):
    ...
```